# Why are United Nations and United Arab Emirates translated as "Объединённые", but United States as "Соединённые"?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, прилагательные, история-языка

Are there two different ways to be "United", or is one simply the more modern usage while the other was used historically in previous centuries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Соединённые** is historical, used AFAIK only with the US and the UK (**Соединённое Королевство**, which loses overwhelmingly to **Великобритания** in frequency of usage. The English term "United Kingdom" dates back to 1707.) As a translation of "united", it would sound "off" nowadays because the word in its current usage properly means "connected", which isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: `in its current usage properly means "connected"` I'd rather say "joined". But, yes, "joined" and "united" are still quite different.

Comment: @Matt More or less the same thing, but I wouldn't put "joined" in this particular answer to avoid creating a potential for confusion. "Joint Chiefs of Staff" is still `объединённый`, and a "joint venture" is a `совместное предприятие`

Comment: The point here being, English doesn't name any entities "Connected" this or that, which mirrors the way `соединённый` is no longer used as a component of any new formal names in Russian — whereas a form of "to join" continues to be used in this way in English.

Answer (score 17):

*Объединять* and its derivatives were not used in Russian before about 1850.

Kostomarov did use it time to time in his works, however, he mostly used *соединить* wherever a modern Russian speaker would have used *объединить*:

> Итак, вместо того чтобы идти соединенными силами на половцев, Владимиру приходилось идти войною на своих.
>
> Рязанские и муромские князья уже прежде были с Андреем заодно, соединенные войною против болгар

So yes, *объединять* is just a more modern word.